# Storybook, move Docs page in last position with storySort

Tags: storybook

I use storybook autodocs feature. But "Docs" page is alwals on top for every components.

I try to use following storySort parameters

```
storySort: {
  order: [
      'Atoms',
      'Molecules',
      'Organisms',
      ['*', 'Docs'],
    ],
  ],
},
```

But "Docs" page still in first position.

How to move "Docs" in last position of stories for each component ?

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround I found for now is to use a custom storySort function.
**But this is not allow you to use a complexe array order like you can have with the basic storySort configuration.**

```js
// preview.ts

storySort: (a, b) => {
  // Order for the root categories
  const order = [
    'Atoms',
    'Molecules',
    'Organisms',
  ];
  const aPaths = a.title.split('/');
  const bPaths = a.title.split('/');
  const rootA = aPaths[0];
  const rootB = bPaths[0];

  const indexA = order.indexOf(rootA);
  const indexB = order.indexOf(rootB);

  if (indexA === indexB) {
    if (a.type === 'docs') {
      return 1;
    } else if (b.type === 'docs') {
      return -1;
    }
    return 0;
  }
  return indexA > indexB ? 1 : -1;
},
```